# Spring Web API, parse URLs

Tags: spring, url, api-design

I'm new in Spring.
I' m developing a Spring Web API and I have problems parsing the URLs with regular expressions. I have already looked at the following posts:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841770/optional-path-variables-in-spring-mvc-requestmapping-uritemplate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516969/spring-mvc-getting-pathvariables-containing-dots-and-slashes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998419/requestmapping-annotation-in-spring-mvc
```

but I haven't found yet a solution to my problem.
I want that all my requests get mapped to a single method, the length of the URL can be variable and the number of parameters can be also variable. I would like to capture the whole URL with the variable `pathValue` and not until the slash <kbd>/</kbd>:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{pathValue}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

All regular expressions that I have tested in Spring capture content between slashes `(/......./)` and don't consider the remaining URL.

The main point is, that I want to parse the URL in a single method and that implies that all requests get mapped to that method.
Is there any way to achieve this in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to dispatch ALL request to one handler then you do not need to have the spring method dispatcher at all.

Instead you can have your own Request handler

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="urlMap">
         <map>
              <entry key="/**" value="myCatchAllResourceHandler" />
         </map>
     </property>
     <property name="order" value="100000" />       
</bean>

<bean id="myCatchAllResourceHandler" name="myCatchAllResourceHandler"
      class="MyCatchAllResourceHandler">
</bean>
```

You have to implement your own Request handler

```
public class MyCatchAllResourceHandler extends HttpRequestHandler() {

    /**
     * Process the given request, generating a response.
     * @param request current HTTP request
     * @param response current HTTP response
     * @throws ServletException in case of general errors
     * @throws IOException in case of I/O errors
     */
    void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                   throws ServletException, IOException;
         System.out.println("I get invoked");       
    }
}
```

**But to be honest, this is almost like throwing all Spring MVC away!**

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, if I use Spring features how can I get Spring to filter incorrect URLS and to show a custom error page, since the number of incorrect URLS is bigger than the correct ones. Is there a way to map incorrect URLs? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to customize the "resource not found" page?

Comment: I want to filter invalid URLS for example: portal/customer/item and portal/recommendation/user/product/book are valid URLS but portal/recommendation is not a valid URL. I want to have a method that determines if a URL is correct or not.